# IterateUntil with a state parameter

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm writing a board game for a class. Control.Monad.Loops has an iterateUntil function which is very close to what I want. However, I want to have my action take a parameter (which is the board state for this turn.) So my question is, how idiomatic is the following? Is there anything I could do to remove the explicit recursion?

```
iterateUntilIO :: (a -> IO a) -> a -> (a -> Bool) -> IO a
iterateUntilIO action state predicate = if predicate state
                                            then return state
                                            else do
                                                nextState <- action state
                                                iterateUntilIO action nextState predicate
```

Comment: I think this is fine -- the idea of encapsulating the loop into a combinator is great.  The only way I can think to make it more naturally idiomatic is to use a guard instead of `if .. then .. else`; e.g. `iterateUntilIO action state predicate | predicate state = ... | otherwise = ...`

Comment: Oh, and this has nothing to do with `IO` specifically, this works in any monad.  I would consider calling this function `untilM`, and giving its type signature `(Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> (a -> Bool) -> m a`.

Comment: Is this not iterateUntilM?

Comment: @argiopeweb Wow, I skipped right by that one! Considering it's just above iterateUntil. Thanks for pointing that out, I thought there might be a pre-made version of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be `iterateUntilM`. Your function can be written as:

```
iterateUntilIO :: (a -> IO a) -> a -> (a -> Bool) -> IO a
iterateUntilIO action state predicate = iterateUntilM predicate action state
```

This also implies you could simply replace `iterateUntilIO` with `iterateUntilM` in your code.